# If neutral line touches the live wire, how to protect the devices connected due to neutral fault?

Tags: fault

If the neutral line accidental touched the live wire, then due to momentary surge the home appliances connected gets damaged, what are the ways to protect the devices. Would RCCB be helpful to protect the home appliances. Initially I thought the devices are burnt due to high voltage hence installed servo stabilizer but even that got affected.

Comment: Whenever it happened to me, the breaker tripped and everything else was fine.

Comment: So, what was the original protection, has it now improved since fitting the RCB?

Comment: Original protection is just MCB which gets tripped but before that the devices are damaged. I need to know if RCCB would be helpful in such case.

Comment: RCCB detects current going to earth from either live or neutral, not current between live and neutral as that's where it normally goes.

Comment: An RCCB would not trip in this case (except due to over-current on the short).  An Arc Fault Interrupter breaker might trip (there are two types, one trips on open/closed circuit arcing and the more advanced one also faults on phase/neutral arcing).

Comment: If my neighbourhood had such strange mains fluctuations I would log the voltages for a while.  Adding a resonant voltage conditioner before your sensitive loads (don't use if for heating or large motors) may be a way to reduce short dips and spikes.  If the supply is really bad then look at inserting a robust UPS on your sensitive loads.

Answer (score 2):

> If the neutral line accidental touched the live wire, then due to momentary surge the home appliances connected gets damaged, what are the ways to protect the devices.

If neutral touches the live wire there will be a surge in current through the short-circuit but the voltage will *drop*. That will typically not cause a *surge* in voltage. The regular MCB should trip.

Answer (score 0):

In many smart homes with sensitive electronics and appliances, I have installed a surge protector at the electrical panel. They do not take up much room. It protects against accidental surges in the 120-240 volts entering the home from such things as lightning strikes.

Comment: Thank you Michel for the info , is the surge protector similar to the MCB and should be connected parallel to the home line circuit?

Comment: The surge protector comes with instructions you should follow and it's been a while since my last installation, but yes, I believe it's smaller than the MCB and the kind we bought were installed just outside the panel with leads entering the panel through the normal 1/2" k.o.

Answer (score 0):

Circuit breakers or fuses will provide protection from short circuits;  shorts quickly develop very high currents and quickly trip breakers or melt fuses.

An RCCB will not do anything extra to stop a line to neutral short.  The RCCB trips when it senses a ground fault when it detects a current imbalance between the line and neutral.   With a line to neutral short, there is high current but no imbalance.